# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \ \pi} \left( \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\cot^2(x)\right)$ without L'hopital's rule or series

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate this limit:

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \ \pi}} \bigg( \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\cot^2(x)\bigg)$$

However I simply can't figure it out. Initially I tried to write the limit as:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \ \pi}} \bigg( \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\bigg)$

and then tried combining it somehow. I then tried to rewrite the denominator as $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$ and then tried to multiply by the conjugate but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I should approach this? I really am clueless at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align}
\mathrm L&={\lim_{x \to \ \pi}} \left( \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\cot^2(x)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos x + \cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}\\&=\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos x(1+ \cos x)}{1-\cos^2 x}\\&=\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos x(1+ \cos x)}{(1-\cos x )(1+\cos x)}\\&=\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos x}{(1-\cos x )}\\&=\frac{-1}{1-(-1)}\\&=-\frac 12
\end{align}

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about factoring... Thanks!

Comment: @FutureMathperson Welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right track! 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \pi }\frac{\cos x(1+\cos x)}{1-\cos^2 x} &= \lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{\cos x}{1-\cos(x)}\\ 
&= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes haha. I forgot to factor!

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \ \pi}} \bigg( \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\cot^2(x)\bigg)
=\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \ 0}} \bigg( \frac{-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\cot^2(x)\bigg)
=\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{\cos x(-1+\cos x)}{1-\cos^2 x} = \lim_{x \to 0}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos(x)}\\ 
= -\frac{1}{2}$$
Given that $\cos( x-\pi)=-\cos x$ and that $\sin (x-\pi)=\sin x$